# Drag from the ListView and Drop on to the Button

Tags: java, android

I would like to know if its possible to drag an item from the ListView and drop onto the Button. After dropping onto the button the text on the button will be changed.

Is it possible to drop an item onto the Button?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that behavior with [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/package-summary.html) except that i don't believe there is quick easy solution